# 2-D character not falling to the ground

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection

I am very new to Game Development and I am making a game with a simple Ragdoll which has a body, a head, and 2 limbs(hands). The head and the limbs are hinged to the body and I have kept the Ragdoll above a cube to be used as the ground on which the Ragdoll falls. Till now, I haven't added any scripts for movement or anything, I just want my Ragdoll to fall on the cube below it properly. But when I click play, the Ragdoll just starts to float above its original position. When I move it through the editor away from the cube(ground), it does fall down. It's like the cube is opposing the downward acceleration of the Ragdoll. The Ragdoll won't land on the cube. All the bodies have Rigid body and collider scripts. The Ragdoll also doesn't disassemble, it manages to keep itself together. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. I researched about this but I have found no solution. I am using the free version of Unity.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your colliders are much larger than the visible portions of your torso or limbs.

In the screenshots you've shown, the green-outlined rectangle and circles are the extents of your colliders. This is the shape that processes collisions with other geometry.

Because these colliders are so huge, they can be resting in surface-to-surface contact with your platform while the visible portion of your body/limbs are still a long distance away, with a lot of apparently-empty space in between. This would account for the "hovering" behaviour you described.

To fix this, adjust the size and offset of your colliders to more accurately match the shape and size of the visual elements whose physical extents they represent. You can do this by editing the numeric fields on the component in the Inspector, or by clicking on the "Edit Collider" button to drag & size the collider visually in the scene view.